# Calling a function in another function

Tags: python

I am trying to call one of my previous functions in another function but I can't seem to get it working, my functions go like this:

```
def order_three(a, b, c):
 if a > b and b > c:
  L = a
  M = b
  S = c
 elif a > c and c > b:
  L = a 
  M = c
  S = b
 elif b > a and a > c:
  L = b 
  M = a
  S = c
 elif b > c and c > a:
  L = b 
  M = c
  S = a
 elif c > a and a > b:
  L = c
  M = a 
  S = b
 else:
  L = c
  M = b 
  S = a
 return(L, M, S)

def tri_test(a, b, c):
  order_three(a, b, c)
  c = L
  b = M
  a = S
  if  a ** 2 + b ** 2 == c ** 2:
    print("Right")
  elif a ** 2 + b ** 2 > c ** 2:
    print("Acute")
  elif a ** 2 + b ** 2 < c ** 2:
    print("Obtuse")
```

I have to determine what kind of triangle it is by sides, so I was thinking if the hypotenuse has to be the longest side then I can call my order function and set c = L, L obviously being largest, and then the rest would fall into place, I can't figure out why it won't work, it says M is not defined even though S and L work from what I can tell, any help? the order function works as intended by the way. Note * the indentation may be wrong because of stack but in my code it is correct

Comment: You probably want to capture the returned values when you call the function: `L, M, S = order_three(a, b, c)`. When you define variables inside a function, they are only scoped there, so `L`, `M`, and `S` are not visible outside `order_three()`

Comment: Instead of all the complicated if, elif ... why not just put the arguments into a List, sort the order and then return a sorted Tuple from `order_three()`

Comment: To elaborate: The body of the function `order_three` could be a one-liner: `return sorted([a, b, c], reverse=True)`

Answer (score 0):

This should be the correct code:

```
def tri_test(a, b, c):
  c,b,a = order_three(a, b, c)       # L is assigned to c, M is assigned to b, and S is assigned to a. Since we are getting this return values from function order_three(a, b, c)
```

---

Complete code:

```
def order_three(a, b, c):
 if a > b and b > c:
  L = a
  M = b
  S = c
 elif a > c and c > b:
  L = a 
  M = c
  S = b
 elif b > a and a > c:
  L = b 
  M = a
  S = c
 elif b > c and c > a:
  L = b 
  M = c
  S = a
 elif c > a and a > b:
  L = c
  M = a 
  S = b
 else:
  L = c
  M = b 
  S = a
 return(L, M, S)

def tri_test(a, b, c):
  c,b,a = order_three(a, b, c)
  if  a ** 2 + b ** 2 == c ** 2:
    print("Right")
  elif a ** 2 + b ** 2 > c ** 2:
    print("Acute")
  elif a ** 2 + b ** 2 < c ** 2:
    print("Obtuse")
```

---

---

As commented by others, you can reduce your code by:

```
def order_three(a, b, c):
    return sorted([a,b,c])[::-1]

def tri_test(a, b, c):
  c,b,a = order_three(a, b, c)
  if  a ** 2 + b ** 2 == c ** 2:
    print("Right")
  elif a ** 2 + b ** 2 > c ** 2:
    print("Acute")
  elif a ** 2 + b ** 2 < c ** 2:
    print("Obtuse")
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic principle of coding is to avoid repeating yourself. So using the comments given and tidying up the code, you could use:

```
def order_three(a, b , c):
    return sorted([a, b, c], reverse=True)

def tri_test(x, y, z):
    large, med, small = order_three(x, y, z)
    large2 = large **2
    tot = med **2 + small**2
    
    if tot >= large2:
        if tot > large2:
            print('Acute')
        else:
            print('Right')
    else:
        print('Obtuse')
```